# Redis 3.0.3 rails undefined method `set'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

So I'm simply trying out redis on ruby on rails
and I keep getting this error .

`undefined method`set' for nil:NilClass`

On my model I created this method

`def self.create_bookmark(bookmark) 
    $redis.set('redis','so its working')
 end`

then simply call it on my controller.

I, have tried the command on my rails console.

`irb(main):022:0>$redis.set('party','Now!!')`

`irb(main):022:0>=>"OK"`

`irb(main):022:0>$redis.get('party')`

`irb(main):022:0>=>"NOW!!"`

The commands seems to be working fine on the console.

Comment: The clue here isn't the part that says `undefined method 'set'`, it's the part that says `for nil:NilClass`. The problem isn't that the method is missing, it's the object you're *calling* it on which is missing

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to give your method a name?

```
def my_method
  $redis.set('redis','so its working')
end
```

Comment: No, I didn't and thank you for noticing 

my method is

`def self.create_bookmark(bookmark) 
     $redis.set('redis','so its working')
 end`

Comment: Where do you put that method?

Comment: sorry for the very late reply, I place the method inside my model bookmark 
then on my controller i called it like this 
`Bookmark.create_bookmark(bookmark_params) `

Comment: how do you setup redis? it seems that you need to add `$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)` to your `config/initializers/redis.rb`.

Comment: yes I've done that already , also tested redis on my rails console .

Comment: That's strange. What if you create connection in-place? `redis = Redis.new(...); redis.set(...)` right in your `create_bookmark` method?

Comment: I'm not on my work place right now, and its the weekend ill give it a shot on monday

Comment: I don't know what happend but its working fine now. I think I only needed to restart the redis server, I'm not sure about this but It wasnt working last fridays but it looks okey now